# 'The number of view controllers provided (2) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested transition'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estou usando `TabBarController` e recebo este erro :

> The number of view controllers provided (2) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested transition

Quando eu saio da tela inicial e ao voltar para ela da este erro. Acho estranho pois na primeira vez que acesso a tela inicial não recebo erro algum é só quando saio dela e retorno ai sim recebo este erro. Já tentei estar também `isdoublesided` para `true` ai da certo mas a tela trava quando eu rotaciono ela. Vou postar o código :

```
let currentViewController : PageContentViewController =          self.pageViewController!.viewControllers![0] as! PageContentViewController
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController]

    let indexOfCurrentViewController = self.indexOfViewController(currentViewController)
    if (indexOfCurrentViewController == 0) || (indexOfCurrentViewController % 2 == 0) {
        let nextViewController = self.pageViewController(self.pageViewController!, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController)
        viewControllers = [currentViewController, nextViewController!]
    } else {
        let previousViewController = self.pageViewController(self.pageViewController!, viewControllerBefore: currentViewController)
        viewControllers = [previousViewController!, currentViewController]
    }

    self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: {done in })
    return .mid
```

Sendo que cai sempre no `if` e erro esta dando na penúltima linha antes de `return .mid`.

Qualquer ajuda agradeço!Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema eu estava deixando meu código dentro de viewWillAppear , ao colocar agora em viewDidLoad funcionou.